Error con Selenium: NoSuchElementException
estoy recibiendo un error al usar Selenium. Mi código es el siguiente:
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#fecha_de_calculo = input('Ingrese fecha de calculo (dd/mm/aaaa): ')

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://auth.afip.gob.ar/contribuyente_/login.xhtml')

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='F1:username']").send_keys('usuario')

time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='F1:btnSiguiente']").click()

time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='F1:password']").send_keys('clave')

time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='F1:btnIngresar']").click()

#Pincho ver todos
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='serviciosMasUtilizados']/div/div/div/div[5]/div/a").click()


#pincho en CCMA - Cuenta corriente de contribuyentes monotributistas y autonomos
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='root']/div/main/div/section/div/div[3]/div[10]/a").click()

time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/div/input[3]").click()


El error que recibo es el siguiente:
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/div/input[3]"}
Otra cosa que probé es modificar el código con una espera explícita pero tampoco me funciona, pasa el tiempo y llega el error "Timed out calculo de deuda"
try:
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/div/input[3]")).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 200).until(element_present)
    print('Elemento encontrado')
except:
    print ("Timed out calculo de deuda")

El campo al que estoy apuntando es feccalculo, resaltado en rojo en la imágen.

lo raro es que si inspecciono el código fuente y busco con CTRL+F por xpath usando la misma cadena que pongo en la consulta me resalta bien el elemento en amarillo, con lo cual entiendo que el xpath es correcto.
Por favor si alguien pudiera ayudarme se los agradecería mucho. Gracias

Es posible que se cree de forma dinamica despues de intentar obtener el elemento.? o que la estructura pueda cambiar en algun caso? intenta extender el tiempo de espera o acceder a cada elemento paso a paso para detectar donde esta el problema. ej: primero; /html/body/table[2], luego /html/body/table[2]/tbody y asi hasta llegar al elemento deseado (o en su defecto encontrar el problema)

Intenté subir el tiempo a 400 y no ayudó (la página carga casi en un instante).  También intenté acceder a cada elemento paso a paso y hasta /html/body responde bien y encuentra el elemento, ya cuando le agrego /table[2] deja de funcionar y no encuentra el elemento. Probé agregando solo /table y no encuentra tampoco. Gracias

Has intentado copiar de nuevo el xPath desde el inspector de elementos.? Cual es el resultado?

Si, lo he intentado varias veces, recién probé a ver si con un selector funcionaba pero tampoco resuelve el problema.


try:
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"body > table:nth-child(12) > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2) > div > input[type=text]")
    print("Element found")
except:
    print("no encontrado")


Es una opcion seleccionar el elemento por el nombre: ej: driver.find_element_by_name("feccalculo") ?

Adicionalmente; verifica que el xparh no sea variable.

driver.find_element(By.NAME,"feccalculo") tampoco funcionó. Como puedo verificar si el XPATH es variable? El punto parece ser lo que me contabas en tu primer mensaje, recorrer la página elemento por elemento, cuando hago eso me encuentra hasta el body, de ahi para abajo ya no encuentra nada, supongo que si eso no se resuelve lo que esta debajo no debería verse tampoco.

Finalmente pude encontrar el problema. El sitio en cuestión estaba abriendo una nueva pestaña en el paso anterior a la línea que arrojaba el error, no encontraba el elemento porque seguía buscando en la pestaña anterior. Modifiqué el código para que busque en la nueva pestaña y ahora todo funciona correctamente. Muchas gracias @JhoubertRincon por la ayuda!

Excelente! Un gusto ayudar. Para saber si el xpath es variable basta con que depures tu codigo y veas el estado del driver durante la ejecucion, asi podrias ejecutar ciertas expresiones para identificar cuando y como cambia
